# How to use if-else statements in Appium Test (Java)

Tags: appium, selenide

I want to use some construction like this in Appium in my Tests:

```
if (element.exists()) {
 System.out.println("OK");
}
```

But Test failed with NoSuchElementException. Thy/catch constructiont doesnt work too.
How can I use if/else statements in Appium?

Comment: Use `isDisplayed()` or `isEnabled()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the element exists or not by first fetching the list of that element and then checking its size. If the size is greater than 0 it means it is present on the page else it is not present.
You can do it like:

```
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("Enter your xpath here"));
if(elementList.size()>0){
   //Element is present
}
else{
   //Element is not present  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public boolean verifyElementIsVisible(){
MobileElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("#enter your id here");

      if(element.isVisible())
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
}
```